# How to read "department" with MSGraph?

Tags: spfx, react, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I'm working on a new Webpart with SPFx and I need only the "department" from every Employee. I have found Code examples, bot no one works at me.

```
import { MSGraphClientV3 } from '@microsoft/sp-http'; 

const getCurrentUser = async  (): Promise<IinterfaceState> => {
  
  const selectProperties: string = `id,department`;
  const requestUrl: string = `/me?$select=${selectProperties}`;
  const client: MSGraphClientV3 = await props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient("3");
  const version: string = 'v1.0';
  const result: IinterfaceState = await client
    .api(requestUrl)
    .version(version)
    .get();

    if (typeof result === 'undefined' || result === null)
    return;
    console.log(result);

  return result;
};
```

With this code:

```
const client: MSGraphClientV3 = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient("3");
```

I get this erreor message on my console:

> Projectname.tsx:45
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getClient')
> at Projectname. (Projectname.tsx:45:79)
> at step (Projectname-web-part.js:97290:23)
> at Object.next (Projectname-web-part.js:97271:53)
> at Projectnam-web-part.js:97265:71
> at new Promise ()
> at vE+m.__awaiter (Projectname-web-part.js:97261:12)
> at Object.getCurrentUser [as onClick] (Projectname.tsx:42:28)
> at BaseButton._this._onClick (BaseButton.js:192:1)
> at Object.

I have no more idea. Anyone other? Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting other context values from `props.context`? Seems like `props.context.msGraphClientFactory` is undefined.

Comment: Maybe...it is not important, but I use "props" in constructor.

Comment: constructor(props:IProjectnameProps){
    super(props);
    this.addListItems = this.addListItems.bind(this);
    this.state = { options:[], 
                   destinations:[], 
                   selectedDepartmentOptions: '', 
                   selectedRubrikOptions: '', 
                   selectedKey: '', 
                   user: []};
  }

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

tsx:

```
  GetUserProfile = () => {
this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3').then((client): void => {
  const selectProperties: string = `id,userPrincipalName,displayName,givenName,surname,employeeHireDate,createdDateTime,department,jobTitle`;
  const requestUrl: string = `/me?$select=${selectProperties}`;
  client.api(requestUrl).get((error: any, user: MicrosoftGraph.User, _rawResponse?: any) => {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(error);
    if(user){
      this.setState({
        data: user
      })
    }
  })
})  


componentDidMount() {
this.GetUserProfile();
```

WebPart.ts:

```
public render(): void {
const element: React.ReactElement<ILaufkundschaftAkWienProps> = React.createElement(
  LaufkundschaftAkWien,
  {
    context: this.context,
    description: this.properties.description,
  }
);

ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
```